# OCaml : Simple function with conditionals doesn't work

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, utop

I am new to OCaml and I am just in process of learning it. I am trying to execute a simple function that calculates `(a+b)^2` or `(a-b)^2` based on the values of `a` and `b`

I am trying to have a function that is as below

```
let a_squared_b a b = 
if(a<0 || b<0) then 
(a**2 + b**2 + 2*a*b) 
 else 
(a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b);;
```

which returns a warning

```
Error: This expression has type int but 
an expression was expected of type float
```

So I tried the one below :

```
let a_squared_b (a:float) (b:float) : float = 
if(a<0 || b<0) 
then (a**2 + b**2 + 2*a*b) 
else (a**2 + b**2 - 2*a*b);;
```

Which also warns something. Hence I proceeded forward to check if the function at least works but it returns wrong result -

```
a_squared_b 2 2;;
- : int = 0
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, OCaml uses different operators for integers and floats, i.e. `( *. )` instead `( * )`, `(+.)` instead `(+)`, etc. Also you should use `2.` instead of `2` to get "variable" of float type.

`# let a_squared_b (a:float) (b:float) : float = 
 if(a<0. || b<0.) 
 then (a**2. +. b**2. +. 2. *. a*. b) 
 else (a**2. +. b**2.  -. 2. *. a*. b);;
 val a_squared_b : float -> float -> float = <fun>

 # a_squared_b 2. 2.;;`

More information you can get, for example, [there](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/a-guided-tour.html#ocaml-as-a-calculator)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even after this correction I am still having the issue when I execute a_square_b 2. 2.;; returns me float 0. Not sure why that is...

Comment: a_squared_b 2.0 2.0 = 0.0 is clear from the definition, since from the condition you are calculating (a-b)^2 when a and b are greather than or equal to 0.0.